# Virtual Environment python 3.6

Tags: python, virtualenv, environment

I'm tring to read a virtual environment that was created on ubuntu using python 3.5 in the python of manjaro. 
It doesnt work, eventhough I have python 3.5 running on my manjaro. 
I've already worked with virtual environment in python before. 
and I was using Ubuntu  and created a virtual enviornment using pyvenv. Now I'm using manjaro. Just typing python it doesnt recognize the python of he virtual enviornment.

Comment: has the venv path changed? In this case I think you should recreate it (possibly from a requirements file).

Comment: It worked here let me  do some tests again

Comment: No didnt work ... I've typed python to enter on the python installed on virtualenv and again the python that worked was from the system.

Comment: did you create the new virtualenv with `python3.6 -m venv venv_name` ?